React function reinvokes when changing state to the same value
I have a react function component that renders a button that when clicked, will set the state variable value to 0. Because the state doesn't change, the component shouldn't get rerendered, and thus the string "OUTSIDE useEffect" shouldn't get logged out. But when I click the button, the string still gets logged out. Why? Here is the code to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-edison-4pkymx?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A4%2C41.
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  console.log("OUTSIDE useEffect");

  function changeValue() {
    setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
    setValue(0);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeValue}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I tried googling and using chatgpt but failed to find an explanation for this phenomenon. I also found out that if I comment the line setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);, it works as I expect, which is clicking the button doesn't print the log. But both calls to setState should be batched afaik.

Do you have any sort of documentation backing your claim that "OUTSIDE useEffect" shouldn't get logged out, or is it just an assumption on your part? The fact that the component function runs doesn't nessecarily mean that the component is re-rendered in the DOM.

I don't have a documentation backing that claim and you're probably right that it's just my assumption. So the real behavior here is that the component function runs but the component is not re-rendered in the DOM? If so, my follow up question would be: when does the function run? I found this github issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/28779 that describes a similar problem and it seems like we have only documented when the component renders but not when the component function runs.

I don't know anything about reacts inner implementations, I only use it. I'm not the right person to answer that. I also wouldn't consider this a problem until I could see that this caused some actual performance issues in my app. Anything costly in terms of computation is usually placed in useEffect or useMemo or similar anyways. In my 5 years of using react this kind of thing has never been an issue for me at least.
